# Convert missing values (-9) to NAs in a Plink PED file when reading into R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two files: `pedigree.ped` and `pedigree.map`. These two file formats can be used by [Plink](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/).

In my case I want use them with R, and I think I must do a conversion to R format. For eg: missing values in Plink are different from missing values in R.

How I can convert these two files to use them in R? How I can change the missing values to NA?

Sample of my data:

**ped file:**

```
1 1 0 0 1.02  A A   G G   0 0
1 2 0 0 0.51  T G   C C   A A
2 3 1 2 -9    0 0   A G   T T
...
```

first column is id_family, second the id_individual, third and fourth are father and mother of the id_individual, fifth is the quantitative trait (-9 : is missing value), the remaining columns are genotypes (SNPs allele). The missing value for columns is 0 except for quantitative trait is -9.

**map file:**

```
1 rs1 0 100000
1 rs2 0 100100
1 rs3 0 100200
```

first column is the id chromosome (1-22, X, Y or 0 if unplaced), the second rs# or snp identifier, third the Genetic distance (morgans), and fourth is Base-pair position (bp units)

Comment: Some sample data would help...

Comment: Assuming that you successfully read the file into an R data.frame, you can check for missing value and assign NA.

Comment: How I can do it? can you give example please?

Comment: The biggest issue here is getting the massive ped files into R - read file will take hours or even days. And the files are too wide for sqldf if using sql lite as the database engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data in the ped file is read into an R data frame -

```
> my.dataframe
  V1 V2 V3 V4    V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1  1  1  0  0  1.02  A  A  G  G   0   0
2  1  2  0  0  0.51  T  G  C  C   A   A
3  2  3  1  2 -9.00  0  0  A  G   T   T
```

Now check for invalid/missing values per column & assign NA. For ex, take the 5th column -

```
my.dataframe[my.dataframe[,5] == -9, 5] <- NA
> my.dataframe
  V1 V2 V3 V4   V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1  1  1  0  0 1.02  A  A  G  G   0   0
2  1  2  0  0 0.51  T  G  C  C   A   A
3  2  3  1  2   NA  0  0  A  G   T   T
```

Similarly assign NA to required entries.

Note: R functions treat NAs in a special way. Look into the respective function arguments. Some related keywords to watch for - `na.rm`, `na.pass`, `na.fail`, `na.omit` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Define NA values when reading ped files into R, e.g.:

```
read.table(text = "
1   1   0   0   1.02    A A G G 0 0
1   2   0   0   0.51    T G C C A A
2   3   1   2   -9  0 0 A G T T",
           na.strings = c("NA", "-9"), sep = "\t")

# result
#   V1 V2 V3 V4   V5  V6  V7  V8
# 1  1  1  0  0 1.02 A A G G 0 0
# 2  1  2  0  0 0.51 T G C C A A
# 3  2  3  1  2   NA 0 0 A G T T
```

Also, use `--tab` option when using [plink](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/reference.shtml#options), so the separator for columns is **tab** and space between genotypes is **space**.

> --tab     Delimit --recode and --recode12 with tabs